# requests post fails when make multiple requests

Tags: python, loops, post, python-requests

I am trying to create a class with which to easily manage the download of various files for a specific web page. The internal requests that are made have the schema:

```
r = requests.post(url,data=data_fun(geom,serie,numPag))
```

The complete post form data extracted from the browser tools is as follows:

[image]

However, doing a lot of tests, I was able to verify that not all of them are necessary. With this, the function data_fun(serie,numPag) builds the form with the parameters that are necessary. It has been verified on multiple occasions that the form works and in fact in a debugging session it was possible to verify that executing the lines step by step there are no problems and in this way the expected response was obtained, however, when the code with the same parameters from any script/command line or even from a debugging session without executing each line manually gets stuck on requests. The function data_fun(serie,numPag) is the following:

```
def data_fun(geom,serie,numPag):
    data = {'geom': 'Polygon',
            'coords': '{"type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [%s]}}]}'%geom,
            'series': '%s'%serie,
            'tipoBusqueda': 'VI',
            'numPagina':'%s'%numPag}
    return data
```

The problem appears when multiple requests are made within a loop, and for some strange reason just because they are made within that loop they return 404, in fact, the same requests made separately one by one return 200:

```
files  = {}
numPag = 1
while numFiles - len(files) > 0:
    r = requests.post(url,data=data_fun(geom,serie,numPag))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        files.update(some_function(r.content))
        numPag += 1
```

I don't understand anything and I have tried different solutions, the first one to let some time pass between requests:

```
import time
files  = {}
numPag = 1
while numFiles - len(files) > 0:
    sleep(0.3)
    r = requests.post(url,data=data_fun(geom,serie,numPag))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        files.update(some_function(r.content))
        numPag += 1
```

The second (which I have found here) has been to make all the requests with the same session passing in the headers:

```
files  = {}
numPag = 1
headers = {
   'Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
   'Connection': 'close',
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
}    
with requests.Session() as session:
    while numFiles - len(files) > 0:
        r = session.post(url,data=data_fun(geom,serie,numPag),headers=headers)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            files.update(some_function(r.content))
            numPag += 1
```

I've also tried combining the two above still to no avail. What would be the correct approach in this situation?

Comment: Can you share the results of your `data_fun` function? If the data in the `post` call has some effect on the authorization, it's possible that the data output is correct only for the first item in the loop

Comment: The difference is `data=data_fun()` vs `data=data_fun(numPag)`, so the error is probably in how `data_fun` handles page numbers.

Comment: @SNygard  I've updated the question to be more specific but I don't think that was the problem anyway.

Comment: `asyncio` and `aiohttp`  probably can solve your problem.